# 'Error: Cannot find symbol @TypeConverters' con RoomDatabase en Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, room

Estaba desarrollando una App sobre ornitología en la que utilizo una BBDD local con Room.

El problema se ha generado al intentar guardar datos de tipo ImageView en una BBDD de Room, para lo cual segun la documentación tenías que utilizar una clase Converter, la cual yo he hecho en kotlin, que no si tendra que ver con el error.

Al intentar iniciar la App recibo el siguiente error:

Converters.kotlin

```
class Converters_kotlin {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBitmap(bitmap:Bitmap): ByteArray{

        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)

        return outputStream.toByteArray()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toBitmap(byteArray: ByteArray):Bitmap{

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)

    }
}
```

Birddb.java

```
@Database(
        entities = {BirdRoom.class},
        version = 1
)
@TypeConverters({Converters_kotlin.class})
public abstract class Birddb extends RoomDatabase {
    private static volatile Birddb INSTANCE;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 1;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    public abstract BirdDAO birdDAO();



    public static Birddb getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Birddb.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            Birddb.class, "user_database")
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Y este es el fragment donde inicializo la BBDD:

CaptureFragment.java

```
public class CaptureFragment extends Fragment {

    private CaptureViewModel mViewModel;
    private ImageButton btnCamara;
    private ImageView mPhotoImageView;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO = 0 /*1*/;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private Uri photoURI;
    private EditText Ettitulo;


    public static CaptureFragment newInstance() {
        return new CaptureFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Ettitulo = (EditText) container.findViewById(R.id.EtInstantanea);

        mPhotoImageView = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imgCapture);
        mPhotoImageView.setImageDrawable(null);

        btnCamara = (ImageButton) container.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //1.Open the camera.

                if (v == mPhotoImageView) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    225);
                        }


                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    226);
                        }
                    } else {
                        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    }
                }

                //2. Recover the photo and write into internal storage.
                //TODO: Use AlerrtDiolog para solicitar nombre de la foto.
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                                //Send the Jornal, and keep into DB.

                                String titulo = Ettitulo.getText().toString();

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("edtValue", titulo);
                                bundle.putString("image", mCurrentPhotoPath);

                                //Swicth the () -> fragment
                                FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                                JournalFragment jf = new JournalFragment();
                                jf.setArguments(bundle);
                                transaction.replace(container.getId(),jf);
                                transaction.commit();

                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foto NO añadida a su diario personal.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

                Intent intento1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File foto = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), mCurrentPhotoPath);
                intento1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(foto));
                startActivity(intento1);

                //3. Set the photo into the ImageView,
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+Ettitulo.getText().toString());

                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap1);

                mPhotoImageView.setImageDrawable(d);

                //4. Ask if the user want to keep that pjoto into his jornal.

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder1.setMessage("¿Le gustaría guardar esta foto en su diario?");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                //Instancio la BBDD local..
                                Birddb db = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext(),
                                        Birddb.class, "database-name").build();


                                //Añado el objeto Bird a la BBDD local.
                                BirdDAO birdDAO = db.birdDAO();
                                //List<Bird> users = userDao.getAll();
                                AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        //Guardar Objeto Bird en la BBDD.


                                        String descripcion = Ettitulo.getText().toString();
                                        BirdRoom bird = new BirdRoom(descripcion, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                                        Birddb.getDatabase(getContext()).birdDAO().insertBird(bird);
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ejemplar añadido correctamente a su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                        "No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha añadido la foto actual a su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();

            }
        });


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_capture, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CaptureViewModel.class);

    }

    private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.");
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        225);
            }
        }if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted CAMERA.");
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        226);
            }
        }

    }





    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                photoURI = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);




            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Si teneís idea de como solucionarlo, gracias de ante mano!

[EDIT]

Añado el error del Logcat:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque no tienes bien configurado kotlin en tu proyecto. Entonces la solución más sencilla es escribir los converters en Java. Quedaría mas o menos así

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static byte[] fromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Bitmap toBitmap(byte[] byteArray) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    }
}
```

Si quieres migrar a kotlin debes agregar a gradle el plugin `kotlin-kapt` y reemplazar tu dependencia `annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` por `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`.

De todos modos guardar imagenes en bases de datos es una mala práctica. En su lugar deberías guardarlas en archivos y almacenar su ruta como string en la base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Implementare la App tal como dices, ya que soy un poco novato todavía no esto, habre hecho 2 App en serio, aunque llevo más mucho tiempo desarrollando.